# Android : How to accomplish auto field calculations in PDF Using qoppa library

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, pdf-viewer

[image]Android : How to accomplish auto field calculations in PDF Using qoppa library.

My Usecase:  In my android app, i have PDF form with three fields. If you change Field A or Field B, Field C will be recalculated to be the sum of Field A and Field B values.

Note : To create form fields and add add JavaScript you will need to have a PDF form designer such as PDF Studio (Qoppa’s desktop PDF editor) or Adobe Acrobat.

- Added image shows you the pdf with javaScript Enabled calculations are performing. Opened using AdobeReader and modified FieldB value and click outside, then FieldC will be updated with Total value automatically.
- When i open the same document in my android app using below snippet auto calculations are not performing. Need Support in this context...

  private void openDocumentUsingQoppa() {

  ```
  // Enable JavaScript
  JavaScriptSettings.setJSEnabled(JavaScriptSettings.ALWAYS);

  StandardFontTF.mAssetMgr = getAssets();
  try {
      pdfDoc = new PDFDocument(strFilePath, null);
      PDFDocument.setKey("XXXXXXXXXXXX"); //, this

  } catch (PDFException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  viewer = new QPDFNotesView(this);
  viewer.setActivity(this);


  setContentView(viewer);
  if(pdfDoc != null) viewer.setDocument(pdfDoc);
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Qoppa's QPDFNotesView which can display and fill interactive PDF forms on Android. You will need to enable JavaScript for the JavaScript calculations to happen in QPDFNotesView.

```
public class JavaScriptActivity extends Activity 
{
    public QPDFNotesView notes;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
           super.onCreate(bundle);

           JavaScriptSettings.setJSEnabled(JavaScriptSettings.ALWAYS);

           notes = new QPDFNotesView(this);
           notes.setActivity(this);
           setContentView(notes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added few more details in the Issue Description, please refer.